# How do you scale the diameter of a cylinder and torus?

Tags: transforms

How do you scale the minor diameter of a torus and diameter of cylinder without changing other dimensions?

Comment: Thank you Crantisz. After alt-S my torus fattens up like a big balloon at the slightest movement of the mouse. I am very new to blender and need some guidance. Your demo illustrates my need perfectly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Than you want to scale radius of torus-like objects, the simplest way is using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> **Shrink-Fatten**:

[image]

Comment: Where'd you get the snazzy Shift-Ctrl-Alt keys?

Comment: +1 btw on Alt-S, didn't think about it

Comment: @bertmoog It is keymon: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5sEcupUJqI

Comment: Ah I see, Linux

Comment: Wow, I tried this on Suzanne.  It was horrible.  But it is definitely a good answer to THIS question.

Comment: @MutantBob lol I had to try. yeah that was...decompressive?

Answer (score 3):

1. Add a torus and don't touch it (don't scale rotate, move etc.)
2. As soon as the torus appears, a menu willl show in the left side in which you can adjust the parameters such as minor and major radius, number of segments, etc.

[image]

Same applies for cylinder and most default shapes.

Comment: Sorry tacofisher. I should have said I want to transform the torus in edit mode.

Comment: No problem, I didn't know about Alt-S either, so thanks for asking this question!